# update_terminal_cwd demystified please?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, iterm, tabs

I am trying to find the documentation on what, exactly, the `printf` command is doing in `update_terminal_cwd`.

If you didn't know already, [the `update_terminal_cwd` function](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/139808/151730) is defined (at least on Mac OS X 10.7.4) in `/etc/bashrc` and in that same file the function is added to the `$PROMPT_COMMAND` so that it runs every time you hit enter in the Terminal.

The text of the `update_terminal_cwd` function itself is as follows:

```
update_terminal_cwd() {
    # Identify the directory using a "file:" scheme URL,
    # including the host name to disambiguate local vs.
    # remote connections. Percent-escape spaces.
local SEARCH=' '
local REPLACE='%20'
local PWD_URL="file://$HOSTNAME${PWD//$SEARCH/$REPLACE}"
printf '\e]7;%s\a' "$PWD_URL"
}
```

This is a few steps down the rabbit hole from trying to [set my Terminal tab names from the command line](http://thelucid.com/2012/01/04/naming-your-terminal-tabs-in-osx-lion/), which can be done [rather easily](https://superuser.com/a/223314/504387), but the tab name gets reset when `ssh`ing into a box.

This led me to [How to stop automatic changing of iTerm titles?](https://superuser.com/q/343747/504387) and the rather obscure [list of control sequences on the Mac](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/X11apps/X11apps-30.1/xterm/xterm-251/ctlseqs.txt).

If you go to that last link and search for the string `osc ps ; pt bel`, you will find the section which defines the escape character that makes tab renaming work.  However, while that explains `printf '\e]1;%s\a'` (note the "1"), it doesn't explain what the "7" does in the `update_terminal_cwd` function I quoted above.

Where is this documented??  (And why does `PWD_URL` include the prefix `file://`?)

Comment: The remote ssh box's prompt might be sending some title-changing strings that reset your local terminal's title.  I noticed that something like `sleep 5` updates part of the tab and window title to be `sleep`, but I'm not sure how it is triggered.

Answer (score 5):

from Terminal.app v2.6.1 (OS X 10.11), under Preferences/Profiles/Window, there is highlighted text "Escape sequence..." which says:

> The working directory and location of the current document may be set
>   using the Operating System Command (OSC) escape sequence:
>
> ESC ] Ps ; Pt BEL
>
> The parameter Ps is either 6 (document) or 7 (working directory) and
>   Pt is a “file:” URL. The URL should include a hostname to disambiguate
>   local and remote paths, and characters must be percent-encoded as
>   appropriate.
>
> When both the working directory and document are set only the document
>   is displayed.

also, from Preferences/Profiles/Tab:

> Window and tab titles may be set using the Operating System Command
>   (OSC) escape sequence:
>
> ESC ] Ps ; Pt BEL
>
> The parameter Ps is either 1 (tab title—aka “icon title”) or 2 (window
>   title) and Pt is the title text.
>
> A custom window title will be displayed within the tab title (along
>   with the other selected items) if there is no custom tab title.
>
> The following example bash command sets the tab title to “My Tab”:
>
> `printf '\e]1;%s\a' 'My Tab'`