# Why do I have a folder with a question mark on my terminal title bar?

Tags: terminal, bash, zsh

I've been trying to solve this for a few weeks now and the only thread I could find with this issue is [this old thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75751/why-does-the-folder-icon-in-my-terminal-have-a-question-mark-overlaid) which did not solve my issue.

[image]

I've checked .bash_profile, .bashrc, .zshrc, .zprofile and apart from a ton of Jupyter lines, I can't seem to locate where this is coming from. Any help is appreciated.

OSX 10.15 Catalina

How can I fix the question mark?

Comment: 2qi1: please ask a separate question regarding Terminal loading times, because it's **probably unrelated** to the question mark...

Comment: @klanomath thanks I will do that, a moderator graciously edited my post already

Comment: Does the folder icon appear any where else, like in the Finder? Does it appear in other apps when you click on the title bar?